# how to check the class of an image in MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I wanted to know if there exists a MATLAB function to know the class of an input image. For example, if the image is either uint8 or double etc? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `class` to tell you the type of an array:

```
>> a = [1,2,3]
>> class(a)
ans = 
double
>> a = uint8([1,2,3])
>> class(a)
ans = 
uint8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isa` function:

```
>> isa( img, 'uint8' ) % returns true if img is of type uint8
>> isa( img, 'single' ) % image is 32bit float
>> isa( img, 'double' ) % image is 64bit float (double precision)
```